# Reducing the publishing rate of a topic from RosLaunch

Tags: ros, urdf, srdf, publish, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a custom-built robot which I am trying to control with move_it. I have written the urdf and generated the srdf using the move_it setup assistant.
All the topics from my URDF are being broadcast on tf links at 30Hz based on a sensor_msgs/JointState  node I wrote. I am trying to link the base of my robot to the vicon `/world` coodinate frame (I am using the [vicon_bridge package](http://wiki.ros.org/vicon_bridge) ). For some reason, I find that the frames being broadcast by vicon are crazily high (to the order of 200 - 400Hz) and as a result, move_it is not updating the tf transforms because of errors such as the following:

My `tf` `view_frames` is given by the attachment in the link http://tinypic.com/r/23uwtmo/9 . Is there a way to specify the publish limit to a nodefrom within a roslaunch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246917/reducing-the-publishing-rate-of-a-topic-from-roslaunch/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [throttle](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle) from the topictools. This is a node that subscribes to a topic and republishes at a defined rate. You can use [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) to make your vicon node to publish e.g. at /tf_superfast and let the throttle subscribe to this and republish on /tf.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-11-01**:
Thank you. Exactly what I needed.